# I want to skip check for maxchar in univocity into my project

Tags: java, univocity

I want to skip the check of setMaxCharPerColumn(10000) of univocity csv parser in my project.
Is there any settings to skip this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the library here. Just set it to `-1`:

```
parserSettings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(-1)`
```